# svn hook script - export just branch checked in

Tags: svn, hook

I've set up a repository to configure my websites, the repository is /subversion/web and at the moment I have just one website controlled in /subversion/web/mywebsite

I've set up a post-commit hook script that exports the site into a web directory on the server for testing before I publish it all separately and it works fine.

What I'd like to do is set the script so that I can control a second website in the same repository but only have 'mywebsite' export when I check in a file related to that project.

I've set it up this way because I access the repository from a number of computers via http, it makes it easier to create new projects without having to create a whole new repository and configure apache to point at it and all the rest of it.

latest svn running on latest ubuntu with latest apache2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using the "svnlook" command.

Here's an example post-commit hook:

```
#!/bin/sh
REPOS="$1"
REV="$2"
/usr/bin/svnlook dirs-changed -r "$REV" "$REPOS" | egrep -q '^mywebsite'
if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then
    # publish site code
fi
```

You may need to run svnlook manually a few times to become familiar with the output and see how to set the match pattern for the grep.